# Python Functions Memory Bleed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function into which I pass variables.  I do not change the names of the variables.

I expect the variable inside the function to be treated as a local variable but in several instances it appears to actually change the variable of the same name outside the function.  I don't think this should be happening.  Anyone experienced it?

So, I have this:

```
def(df1,df2,df3)

    df1.set_index('A',inplace=True)

    df2['c'] = df1['B'] * df3['G']

    return df2
```

I am finding that `df1.set_index('A',inplace=True)` is changing `df1` outside the function.  So when I call the function again I get an error because the function doesn't "see" df1['A'] in df1.  It sees df1 passed from the "outside" as having the index set to 'A' already in an earlier call.

Anyone get this kind of memory bleed?

Comment: That's precisely what you're *explicitly telling* it to do, with `inplace=True`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html. *"I expect the variable inside the function to be treated as a local variable"* - with mutable values, that's not a useful expectation.

Comment: When you pass `inplace = True` , It change the original data as both are having the same reference. If you do not want that, use different variable with `inplace = False`. e.g `df1 = df1.set_index('A',inplace=False)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: You appear to be modifying `df2` but returning `df3` - this is pretty confusing!

Comment: @sam @jonrsharpe so `inplace` transcends the my local variable status?  Instead of just changing the local variable of the same name as the one outside the function it changes it in BOTH places?

Answer (score 2):

In Python function, parameter values are passed by assignment (*the parameter passed in is actually a reference to an object, but the reference is passed by value*), so if you modify `df1` you're modifying the dataframe that was passed as paramter in the function.

You might want to use [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

```
def func(df1,df2,df3):
    df1 = df1.copy()
    df1.set_index('A',inplace=True)

    df2['c'] = df1['B'] * df3['G']

    return df3
```

Note : By default **`deep`** parameter of the copy function is `True`, so might use memory, because of data duplication.

Comment: Please stop using inappropriate terminology. If python used "pass by reference" then rebinding a parameter in the function would affect the caller namespace too, which is not the case.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers rectified.